# Post Request return 404 for Spring Boot with Postman

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am trying to use postman to test one of the post requests I created for my spring boot application. My post requests through postman always return 404.

- I have created a same mapping route for a get request and with the postman, the get request works as expected.
- I have tested with aws cli and made sure that I have the correct access key and secret key for uploading files to S3.

Code for my services

```java
@Service
public class AmazonClient {

    private AmazonS3 s3client;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.endpointUrl}")
    private String endpointUrl;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.accessKey}")
    private String accessKey;
    @Value("${amazonProperties.secretKey}")
    private String secretKey;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initializeAmazon() {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(this.accessKey, this.secretKey);
        this.s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2).withCredentials(
                new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
    }

    @Async
    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile, boolean enablePublicReadAccess) {
        String fileUrl = "";
        System.out.println("Reach");
        try {
            File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
            String fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
            System.out.println("FileName: " + fileName);
            fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
            PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(this.bucketName, fileName, file);

            if (enablePublicReadAccess) {
                putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
            }
            s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
            file.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return fileUrl;
    }

    private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }

    private String generateFileName(MultipartFile multiPart) {
        return new Date().getTime() + "-" + multiPart.getOriginalFilename().replace(" ", "_");
    }


    public String deleteFileFromS3Bucket(String fileUrl) {
        String fileName = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        s3client.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName));
        return "Successfully deleted";
    }
}
```

Code for my controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/storage/files")
public class BucketController {

    private AmazonClient amazonClient;

    @Autowired
    BucketController(AmazonClient amazonClient) {
        this.amazonClient = amazonClient;
    }


    @GetMapping
    public String getFile(){
        return "Files";
    }

    @PostMapping("/file")
    public String file() {
        return "Reach!";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String uploadFile(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("Reach!!");
        return this.amazonClient.uploadFile(file, true);
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    public String deleteFile(@RequestPart(value = "url") String fileUrl) {
        return this.amazonClient.deleteFileFromS3Bucket(fileUrl);
    }
}
```

My security config:

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/index").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/storage*").permitAll();
```

Through postman, I have selected a POST request and put `http://localhost:8080/storage/files/file`, in the body, I have entered a key "file" and set the value to a file type and chose a file from my local.
Here is the response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-09-02T19:09:54.864+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/storage/files/file"
}
```

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRDIU.png)

[Postman Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k9tg.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly your security config interfering.

Have you tried: `.antMatchers("/storage/**")` instead?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried with /storage/** and I am still getting the same error, one thing to mention is that I am able to get the response: "Files" from the same get API call.

Comment: Based on your controller, you should be only getting that response for `GET /storage/files`, not `GET /storage/files/file`. It's not an apples to apples comparison